# get callback arguments from sinon.spy inside promise javascript

Tags: javascript, callback, promise, mocha.js, sinon

I'm running a test using mocha and sinon to get a callback value from inside a promise scope of HTTP-request and it doesn't work due to the async nature of promises. It's because by the time sinon.spy checks on callback, It would have been vanished already and become empty or undefined. Here's the testing code:

```
 it('should issue GET /messages ', function() {
  server.respondWith('GET', `${apiUrl}/messages?counter=0`, JSON.stringify([]));
  let callback = sinon.spy();
  Babble.getMessages(0, callback);
  server.respond();
  sinon.assert.calledWith(callback, []);
});
```

and the promise:

```
function requestPoll(props) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open(props.method, props.action);
            xhr.timeout = 500; // time in milliseconds
            if (props.method === 'post' ) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            }
            xhr.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
                    resolve(e.target.responseText);
            });

            xhr.send(JSON.stringify(props.data));


    });
}
```

**and the call which I'm trying to get callback from on sinon.spy**

```
getMessages: function(counter, callback){

            requestPoll({

                            method: "GET",
                            action: "http://localhost:9090/messages?counter="+counter

            }).then(function(result){

                    callback(result);
            });


        }
```

sinon.spy says it didn't have any arguments (due to async functionality). I tried to look for a way to get result outside the scope and put it on callback.yet I found out it was impossible. also tried resolve and promise return but didn't succeed.

**How can I make this unit test pass?**

Edit:
this is my attempt:

```
getMessages: function(counter, callback){

            var res;
            res = httpRequestAsync("GET",'',"http://localhost:9097/messages?counter=",counter);

            console.log(res);
            if(res!="")
                    callback( JSON.parse(res) );                      
        }
```

I put the request in a separate function:

```
function httpRequestAsync(method,data,theUrl,counter)
    {

            return requestPoll({

                    method: method,
                    action: theUrl+counter,
                    data: data

            }).then(JSON.parse);

    }
```

It returned `res` as the promise and inside its prototype there's the promised value I need. 
[image]

**How can I access that promised value over there?**

Comment: Make `getMessages` return a proper promise instead of taking a callback, that will lead to both better and easier testable code.

Comment: Can you show me? I tried return promise a couple of times. @Bergi what do I need to write under "then" to return a proper promise?

Comment: You just omit the `then`, and put a `return` in front of your expression. Please show us your attempt.

Comment: @Bergi I added my attempt to the question. How can I return the expression right?

Comment: Drop all the lines except the `return requestPoll({…});`, and remove the `callback` parameter. If you need to parse the result, add `.then(JSON.parse)` to that. Then change all calls to use the promise instead of passing a callback.

Comment: I really do need to pass a callback. Is there an option to do so with the callback parameter for the test to pass?

Comment: No, you really don't. Just write `getMessages(5).then(thecallback)` where you call this function.

Comment: @Bergi Well I did more or less as you said and put it in a separate request function. I had already tried this before I posted this question. Now I have the same problem as before. How can I access the prototype promised value? I understood it was impossible.

Comment: See Yury's answer below. You should not put it in a separate function, you should just use `getMessagesAsync` that returns a promise. You can easily use that with an asynchronous test then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you not to mix promises and callbacks. If you already have promise based function stick with it

First make `getMessages` not to break promise chaing. Make it return a Promise

```
getMessages: function(counter) {
  return requestPoll({
    method: "GET",
    action: "http://localhost:9090/messages?counter=" + counter
  }).then(JSON.parse)
}
```

Then use this promise in your test

```
it('should issue GET /messages ', function() {
  server.respondWith('GET', `${apiUrl}/messages?counter=0`, JSON.stringify([{testdata}]));
  const gettingMessages = Babble.getMessages(0);
  server.respond();

  // return a promise so testing framework knows the test is async
  return gettingMessages.then(function(messages) {
      // make assertion messages is actually testdata
  })
})
```